# Exporting sql file from data base via symfony admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I created an admin panel using symfony admin bundle & linked it to a data base.
I want to create a button into that adminBundle dashboard that allow me to export the data-base tables just like the way it's done in phpmyadmin (into sql format or specifying hte format before exporting)
There is a function in sonata admin bundle called `getExportFields()` but I didn't understand how to used, I googled it & tried but no result.
I wonder also how to clean that data-base tables entries via a button in the same interface (without deleting the tables themselves).

Answer (score 1):

The AdminBundle rely on the exporter lib to export data. However, there is no SQL Writer available. You should create a custom action to create this export.